# cin is checking for malformed input, but also now crashes on EOF

Tags: c++, error-handling, cin

So I'm reding input through cin in this while loop:

```
while (getline(cin,s))
{
    cin >> name;
    if (!cin)
        exit(1);

    cin >> age;
    in (!cin)
        exit(1);
}
```

to read a file for a project (there are more cin statements, but it's all the same little code bit). Unfortunately, it's required we use cin (not fstream) and exit(1) upon hitting malformed input. The problem with this is that when I hit a blank line at the end of a file, cin sees it as bad and exits when it shouldn't.

Any ideas?

Thanks much.

**edit** the file looks like this:

Name Age Job $Salary

```
John 55 Worker $55 
Bob 23 Boxer $23 
Susie 26 Secretary $77
```

etc

Comment: What does your input file look like?

Comment: ^each person is on a different line, but I can't show it in the comment. i'll edit the question

Comment: Well, the way your code is now, the entire line is read into `s`, then `std::cin` reads `Bob` and `23`. Next, it repeats and `Boxer $23` is read into `s`. I don't imagine this is what you were going for.

Comment: weirdly enough, since name is a string and age is an int, it works correctly. 

it just reads in the EOF, thinks it's malformed input, and exits.

Comment: Well, EOF is counted as failing input. It sets a flag that causes `cin` to evaluate to `false`.

Comment: is there a way to differentiate EOF from something that's missing?

Comment: The `eof()` member function tells you if the EOF flag has been set due to a read reaching EOF prior to that check. `clear()` resets the flags.

Comment: And please don't misunderstand the `eof()` function. If stdin contains `5<EOF>`, `std::cin >> someInt;` will not cause `eof()` to be `true`. Another `std::cin >> something;`, however, will actually run into EOF, so it will.